# Fast movie creation using MATLAB and ffmpeg

Tags: matlab, animation, video, ffmpeg

I have some time series data that I would like to create into movies. The data could be 2D (about 500x10000) or 3D (500x500x10000). For 2D data, the movie frames are simply line plot using `plot`, and for 3D data, we can use `surf`, `imagesc`, `contour` etc. Then we create a video file using these frames in MATLAB, then compress the video file using `ffmpeg`.

To do it fast, one would try not to render all the images to display, nor save the data to disk then read it back again during the process. Usually, one would use `getframe` or `VideoWriter` to create movie in MATLAB, but they seem to easily get tricky if one tries not to display the figures to screen. Some even suggest plotting in hidden figures, then saving them as images to disk as `.png` files, then compress them using `ffmpeg` (e.g. with `x265` encoder into `.mp4`). However, saving the output of `imagesc` in my iMac took 3.5s the first time, then 0.5s after. I also find it not fast enough to save so many files to disk only to ask `ffmpeg` to read them again. One could `hardcopy` the data as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071607/matlab-using-the-gpu-for-saving-an-image-off-a-figure) suggests, but I am not sure whether it works regardless of the plotting method (e.g. `plot`, `surf` etc.), and how one would transfer data over to `ffmpeg` with minimal disk access.

This is similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533922/how-to-make-a-video-from-a-3d-matrix-in-matlab), but `immovie` is too slow. This post [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25659782/generating-animations-in-matlab-avi-files-without-displaying-figure) is similar, but advocates writing images to disk then reading them (slow IO).

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you're trying to do is to convert your data into an image by doing the same kind of operation that `surf`, or `imagesc` or `contour` is doing and then writing it to a file directly, that would keep all the data in the memory until writing is needed.

I had little experience with real images that could also work here:
I saw that calling `imshow` took lot of time, but changing the `CData` of a presetted figure created by the `imshow` function took around 5ms, so, maybe you could set a figure using any of the function you like, and then update the underlying `XData`, `YData` etc. so that the figure will update in the same fashion?

best of luck!

Comment: Can't believe you actually dug this almost dead post up. Nice! Have you tried implementing your suggestion to see if it works?